# Can .htaccess block only url requests, but still allow downloads via HTML?

Tags: html, .htaccess, download, anchor

I have a number of files inside a `/downloads` folder which I'd like to restrict access to. I'd like the files to be accessible only via a `<a download href="/relative/file/path.pdf">` element on a page within my file structure. I am aware of various ways to achieve this through using PHP to handle download requests and serve files based on session tokens etc, but my files are giant and that's not how I'd like to handle this problem.

I know `.htaccess` can deny access to a folder or file entirely, but my question is this: Can `.htaccess` **restrict** access to a file or folder based on the means of arriving at said file or folder? As in, can `.htaccess` deny a url request but allow a download via a relative file path? Or is there some other way to achieve this that I am not aware of?

Comment: This is not really possible. There are various attempts, but nothing that is robust or reliable. Reason simply is this: what you ask makes little sense in a web environment. You are trying to hold something back that you published. That makes little sense, once you about it...

Comment: @arkascha I understand what I'm trying to do and I disagree that it makes little sense. "Holding back something that you published" is a concept that can be applied to a bunch of stuff online. Any content that's available only to a user that is signed in to a given platform is "holding back something you published".

Comment: No, you miss understood what I said. Certainly there are ways and motivations to limit access to resources. Business models are based on that, often. But that is another thing. What I referred to is the technical level, the situation you currently have. You published something, by that I mean you made it available via http. Now you try to limit that access afterwards which won't work in a reliable way, that is all I say. You'd need a completely different approach if you really want to control access.

Comment: @arkascha it is that "completely different approach" that I am interested in, then. I already am using session tokens through a login to provide access to the download options, so is there a way I can use PHP to serve these files for download only on click of said button? I mean, I know I can do this, but my files are in some cases several hundred MB and I'm under the impression that this poses a problem to this method.